# Floated div dropping below others in IE and FF

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

I'm having an odd problem with some floated divs on [this page that I'm working on](http://www.woodexperts.com). There are 3 of them across the page, with 1em margins between. In Chrome they line up perfectly, but in IE and FF, the right hand one drops a little - but not all the way below. I thought this might be best described with a picture, please see below:

[image: Illustration of positioning problem.]

I can't work out which bit of the CSS is causing this - I've been through the new FF code inspector and highlighted all block level objects with the webdev toolbar but can't see anything that would cause such a drop.

I did wonder if it was something within the JS twitter feed causing it, but I've swapped round the Twitter and "Update" boxes and it's always the right-hand one. I've also tried removing additional elements from the page - everything between the menu and these three boxes.

I must admit, I'm at my wit's end! Can anyone spot something obvious I've missed? The CSS is fairly large, and I'm not sure which bit to show, so I haven't copied it in in, but will do if anyone desires. Otherwise everything can be viewed at http://www.woodexperts.com

Comment: Work's fine in all of my browsers. The whole site looks pretty messed up in IE7 if you're planning on supporting it though.

Comment: I haven't exactly gone through it properly, but in IE9 if you change on `div#main div.tricolumn` the `padding-right: 1em` to `padding-right: 0.9em`, it's fixed. If that's "good enough" as an answer, let me know..

Comment: @JamesHay Thanks, I'd not spotted that - typical!

Comment: @thirtydot,  I'd assumed it wasn't a spacing issue because it had only dropped a couple of em down, but you are correct! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `width: 15.25em` in `div#main div.tricolumn` to `width: 15.24em`

That should take care of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'd assumed it wasn't a spacing issue because I would have thought that would have forced it all the way onto the next row, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a hack, but if IE is the only browser causing problems, you might want to consider IE conditional comments that restrict certain styles only for IE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx